# Why am I getting an Undefined Index Error?

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

```
<?php  
$p = $_GET['page'];

$page = $p.".php";

if(file_exists($page))
    include($page);
elseif($p=="")
    include("home.php");
else
    include("404.php");

?>
```

This block of code is giving me an Undefined Index error for the $page variable, i tried 
doing this......

```
<?php  
$p = $_GET['page'];

if(isset($page)){$page = $p.".php";}

if(file_exists($page))
    include($page);
elseif($p=="")
    include("home.php");
else
    include("404.php");

?>
```

but this did nothing. I'm still a novice at PHP and I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this.
Any suggestions?

EDIT: For everyone wanting the url: http://memphislinuxboy.tk/
ALso, for those of you wanting to know about security, the included file must be .PHP

Comment: does your url contains somthing like this....?page=xxx....if not you are not getting any get variable with name 'page'

Comment: This code scares me : `?page=/etc/php.ini`

Comment: @CD001 Why because you think someone can access it using a `$_GET`? Couldn't the OP use => `<Files php.ini>order allow,deny deny from all</Files>` in `.haccess` to protect it?

Comment: @Fred read what you've written and think about it a little with regards to how PHP's include() function works.

Comment: @Fred, he could, but its better to select what files are allowed by using a pattern or predetermined list to check against. if apache was configured incorrectly, he could just as well use /etc/passwd.

Comment: @CD001 I'm sorry, but I'm not as well-versed in that area as others are. Yet can you explain what you wrote? I was curious about your comment `?page=/etc/php.ini`

Comment: `/etc/php.ini` could be `/etc/passwd` should OP be denying all files like this? :P

Comment: @CD001 Anything to do with "Remote File Inclusion" perhaps? I  Google'd what you wrote, and I am researching this now. When you wrote your comment, I knew right away that it wasn't good. I thought that it could be protected with what I wrote. Like I said, I'm not that well-versed in that area, but I am good at doing research, which is what I am doing right now.

Comment: @CD001 Ok, I've done enough research now to understand what you meant now. Thanks for that bit of information, I'd of never known about it otherwise, cheers. (*"Peace"*)

Comment: the included file must be a .php file everyone

Comment: @Fred sorry, I was in the car else I'd have replied - but yeah, you got the point ;) Essentially PHP probably runs as the webserver user and can happily include anything ;)

Comment: @JamieTaylor you've got it backwards, it shouldn't have a "blacklist" at all but a "whitelist" - if you wanted to be really strict about it you'd use something like PHPTAL and never use the include construct to pull in things like PHP files at all (except your library files of course - and you'd `require` those)

Comment: @CD001 Not a problem. It gave me time to look into this, and all this time I've been learning PHP in the past 2 years, something told me not to use `$_GET` methods for fetching URLs. I can't explain it, but I listen to what my instincts tell me and they're usually "right on the money". Again, thanks for pointing that out, you've helped me "see the light" *as it were*, cheers!

Comment: @lilo346 don't rely on the file extension alone to protect you, if you've got URL Wrappers enabled on include then I could pass in `/?page=http://mysite.ext/phpinfo` to include a phpinfo.php page - or better yet a script that dumps out your database connection string.

Comment: @lilo346 and here's an example of what's wrong with your code `http://memphislinuxboy.tk/?page=index` will send your page into a terminal loop.

Comment: @CD001 thanks, i actually got this from a tutorial, and i never noticed.

Comment: @CD001 I was being sarcastic, I realise that doesn't transfer well over the internet :P

Answer (score 3):

I'd imagine `$_GET['page'];` isn't set, check the URL going in to make sure it contains "page=" at some point.

You can fix this with

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) {
    //your code
}
```

---

Off topic:

```
if(file_exists($page))
    include($page);
```

You're attempting to include a file specified by the client. This could be a serious security flaw if not handled correctly. It's probably best to check against a list of known (good) files.

Comment: I don't care if the off-topic is off-topic ... it needed stating! ;)

Comment: that kind of insert causes a 404 on my site. :) but thanks for the info!

Comment: Which line? nothing here should be causing a 404 unless your input is wrong

Answer (score 0):

the line `$p = $_GET['page'];` is throwing the error.

You're attempting to access an array element that has not yet been set.

Check to make sure the value exists before using it.

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
else
{
    // this is the page they'll have if they havnt specified one
    $page = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['page']` is not set in your code your url needs to contain `?page=somepage`

```
<?php  

    $page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home') . '.php';

    if(file_exists($page)){
        include($page);
    } else {
        include("404.php");
    }

?>
```